sp_blitzwho - best way to filter out system or background services
When running sp_blitzwho, short of modifying the proc itself, is there a simpler way to filter out system-related queries such as broker, traces, etc?
This is on Azure Sql Managed Instance, and we are using SignalR, which seems to be showing up in our blitz output. I know I can create a separate proc to put the output to a new table, then query the table without the WAITFOR statements, but I scoured the parameters and couldn't find anything that would remove it.


Nm, I looked through the parameter list again and figured it out:
Create my own stored proc with the following:
drop table if exists 'tempdb.dbo.blitzWhoOutput'
exec sp_blitzwho @OutputDatabaseName = 'tempdb', @OutputSchemaName = 'dbo', @OutputTableName = 'blitzWhoOutput'

select * 
from tempdb.dbo.blitzWhoOutput
where wait_info not like 'BROKER_RECEIVE_WAITFOR%'
order by elapsed_time desc

